# Yarn Fair Scheduler not distributing resources evenly

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I have an AWS EMR cluster setup with Yarn Fair scheduler.  Currently, if I start a large job (job A), it starts and takes up all the CPU and Memory of the cluster.  If I start a second job (job B) while the cluster is being maxed out from job A, it goes into accepted state, but not running.  Even with autoscaling turned on and new nodes are added to the cluster, the new resources are being allocated to job A and not job B. Job B, meanwhile, continues to wait until Job A completes or is killed.  I do not have preemption enabled as I do not want to kill tasks in job A.

Is there a way to free up resources by Job A and give them to Job B?

Can I set a limit percentage a job can take up on the cluster so it leaves room for other jobs?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't enable preemption, you cannot free up resources.  You could set up 2 queues and enable the `maxResources` in that queue job A runs on so it cannot take all the resources.

Refer to Ray Chiang and Dennis Dawson's article [Untangling Apache Hadoop YARN, Part 5: Using FairScheduler queue properties](https://blog.cloudera.com/untangling-apache-hadoop-yarn-part-5-using-fairscheduler-queue-properties/) for specifics on how to do this.